# python except and finally do not work with KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python-2.7, try-except, keyboardinterrupt

After executing the following code, when I press control+C, the execution ends and nothing is printed to the console

```
import time

x = 1

try:
    while True:
    print x
    time.sleep(.3)
    x += 1

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Bye"


finally:
    print "this one"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is indentation problem in your code. If changed to:

```
import time

x = 1

try:
    while True:
        print x
        time.sleep(.3)
        x += 1

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print "Bye"


finally:
    print "this one"
```

Output is:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
Bye
this one
```

Comment: I copy pasted your code...still doesn't work...it prints the numbers but neither of the messages

Comment: The problem occurred when I executed the code in sublime text, works perfectly fine when run from terminal

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurred when I executed the code in sublime text, works perfectly fine when run from terminal